# Why is my Mac opening Messages every time I take a screenshot?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, ichat

When I take a screenshot on my Mac (OS X Sierra), either with Command-Shift-3 or Command-Shift-4, my Messages app opens with the screenshot and nothing is saved to my Desktop.  In Terminal I confirmed that my defaults for com.apple.screencapture only contains a location setting, and that location IS my desktop.  What could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Check your Keyboard settings too, or other shortcut-type tools.  You might have re-mapped the key sequence at some point.

Answer (score 0):

From [this apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8242934), it may be worth rebuilding the LaunchServices database: paste the code below in a terminal window and hit enter:

```
find /System/Library/Frameworks -type f -name "lsregister" -exec {} -kill -seed -r \;
```